# Not able to install ruby 2.3.1 in ubuntu 22.01 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3

Not able to install ruby 2.3.1 in ubuntu 22.01 using rbenv it is giving the fllowing error response:

```
vidur@Vidur-PC:~/rails_apps/Connectivity-Web$ rbenv install 2.3.0
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /home/vidur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0

Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.0...

WARNING: ruby-2.3.0 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.10 using ruby-build 20230424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.log

Last 10 log lines:
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/store.rb:749:in `save'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/generator/ri.rb:27:in `generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:535:in `block in generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:530:in `chdir'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:530:in `generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.KXKRoa/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:513:in `document'
    ./bin/rdoc:20:in `<main>'


make: *** [uncommon.mk:442: rdoc] Error 1
```

please suggest the possible solution thanks in advance.

```
File looks like:

   99% [939/945]  vm_dump.c
 99% [940/945]  vm_eval.c
 99% [941/945]  vm_exec.c
 99% [942/945]  vm_insnhelper.c
 99% [943/945]  vm_method.c
 99% [944/945]  vm_trace.c
100% [945/945]  vsnprintf.c

Generating RI format into /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/.ext/rdoc...
Marshal.dump reentered at marshal_dump
/tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:866:in `dump'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:866:in `save_class'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:750:in `block in save'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:749:in `each'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:749:in `save'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/generator/ri.rb:27:in `generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:535:in `block in generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:530:in `chdir'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:530:in `generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20230425170734.32179.NAWMdR/ruby-2.3.1/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:513:in `document'
    ./bin/rdoc:20:in `<main>'


make: *** [uncommon.mk:442: rdoc] Error 1
```

Comment: What does the log at `/tmp/ruby-build.20230425154726.452387.log` look like?

Comment: Looks like an issue with rdoc. Try running `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install...` to disable rdoc generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @benj-p pointed out in the comments, the crash happens with rdoc.

Disabling rdoc fixes this issue for 2.3.1 (and 2.3.2 and 2.3.3)

`RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install`

More information in the thread that introduces and describes this [at the ruby-build repo](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/156)